# Fireworks kern value into css

Tags: css, fireworks

I have to text in fireworks that I kerned at "12". I am not trying to translate this value into css. Does it translate as 12%? .12em... How would I convert it?

Comment: I think it depends on what you have the drop down set to (% or px)

Comment: that function is available for leading but not kerning... there is no % or px for kerning

Answer (score 0):

My colleague found a great article:
http://justinmarsan.com/css-letter-spacing-in-photoshop-and-browsers/

The calculations are also good in fireworks.

Fireworks or photoshop to em formula:

> X / 1000 = Y
>
> Where X is the value of the letter-spacing in Photoshop and Y is the value in em to use in CSS

Fireworks or photoshop to px formula:

> X * S / 1000 = P
>
> Where X is equal to the letter-spacing value in Photoshop, S is the font-size in pixels (which is equal to the value in point provided you’re working in 72dpi) and P is the resulted value in px to use in CSS